# Cannnot "gem install json -v "1.8.2""

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

```
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /Users/Sean/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/json-1.8.2/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing json (1.8.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.8.2'` succeeds before bundling.
```

> Above this line is the log which is produced from the command line. I
>   don't know how to make it install.

Comment: Run `gem install json -v '1.8.2'` from the command line as it says, and see what comes up. Usually this step will give more details about what is wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: have you tried sudo gem install json -v '1.8.2'? Does the directory actually exist?

Comment: what plataform are you using?